# Multiple JMS Listener With Different Hosts With Spring

Tags: jms, spring-jms

I am trying to achieve a result using Spring. In my case; I need to connect to a queue on n (~6) different hosts/ports. Say,

jms://hostA:portA/Queue
jms://hostB:portB/Queue
jms://hostC:portC/Queue
...

I am completely lost on where to start now. Reading tons of documents and it broke my whole motivation.

p.s; All the examples and documentations are mostly focused on ActiveMQ which in my case is not valid.

I do not need any code sample but a light on my way to start from. Like a some class names to check etc..

Answer (score 1):

The JMS provider is irrelevant.

You need a connection factory bean for each host and configure each component (JMS template, listener container, etc) to use the appropriate connection factory.

Comment: This is the same for WebLogic JMS as well right ? I am still checking and find out that I can use wljmsclient and wlclient to get to ConnectionFactory implementation. I assume WL is similar to ActiveMQ to provide a connectionfactory.

Comment: Correct - all JMS providers have a `ConnectionFactory`. In most cases with Spring, this is wrapped in a `CachingConnectionFactory` (especially on the producer side, for performance reasons).

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try. I am on the consumer side btw.

Comment: I finally figured it out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59734256/defaultjmslistenercontainer-using-beanfactorypostprocessor (this contains a minimal piece of code I did use). Inspired by the page; https://blog.pchudzik.com/201705/dynamic-beans/

since this took too much on my time; I am fully open to help people if they need assistance for such requirement. Don't get lost in the hidden rooms of Spring when someone already lost and found a way out.