# DefaultJmsListenerContainer using BeanFactoryPostProcessor

Tags: spring, jms, spring-jms

I am currently trying to support dynamic multiple jms provider scenario in my application. So far I did achieved to create DefaultMessageListenerContainer using post processor. Cool part is that the DefaultMessageContainerListener has destinationName property where you can easily set the queue to be listened/sent for messages.

However, the `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory` has no such method to set the queue name. I do reached at around the `SimpleJmsListenerEndpoint` that the `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory` using to initiate the container. But I am unable to find how to set it. Please see below what I did so far.

```java
beanDefinitionRegistry.registerBeanDefinition("messageListenerContainer", 
    BeanDefinitionBuilder.rootBeanDefinition(DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory.class)
                         .addPropertyReference("connectionFactory", "queueConnectionFactory")
                         .addPropertyReference("destinationResolver", "jndiDestinationResolver")
                         .addPropertyValue("concurrency", concurrency)
                         .addPropertyValue("sessionAcknowledgeMode", Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE)
                         .getBeanDefinition()
);
```

But as you can see I can not set the queue endpoint for listening. How can I do that from here?

Comment: Where are you defining `jndiDestinationResolver`?

Comment: The same way I do create listenerContainer. `registerBeanDefinition` with the definition of `JndiDestinationResolver.class` and adding properties of `jndiTemplate` as bean refferance, `cache` as property